# Access a key that is not always present in multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to iterate through a dictionary and access a unique key value. For example, I would like to print the value of 'maidenName'

```
{'key1': {'firstName': 'bob',
          'lastName': 'smith',
          'middleName': 'joe'},
'key2': {'firstName': 'jane',
          'lastName': 'jackson',
          'middleName': 'marie',
          'maidenName': 'sanchez'}}
```

Normally, I would iterate through the dictionary by:

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    print v['maidenName']
```

But no luck.

Comment: " 'maidenName': 'sanchez' " doesn't belong to a key. Is it correct?

Comment: These braces aren't even balanced. This isn't a valid dict, and if we can't tell how your data structure is structured, we can't tell you how to access its data.

Comment: Avoid using `dict` as a name for a variable, it shadows (clobbers) the builtin `dict`, making it unusable in following code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code throws an error because `maidenName` doesn't exist in the first.
You can use `dict.get()` to avoid this:

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    print v.get('maidenName')
```

You can also use get to print a message that no maiden name exists, e. g.:

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    print v.get('maidenName', '<no maiden name given>')
```

Comment: No, if you look at the data, `maidenName` is not present in the value dicts at all.

Comment: @Coldspeed i agree but i think it's a typo

Comment: @PRMoureu I appreciate your help. This is answered my question.

Comment: Note that `<dict>.get(<key>)` will be `None` if the key does not exist and no default value (the optional second argument to `.get(_, <default>)`) is provided

Answer (score 2):

Considering Dict is:

```
>>> dict = {'key1': {'firstName': 'bob',
...                  'lastName': 'smith',
...                  'middleName': 'joe'},
...         'key2': {'firstName': 'jane',
...                  'lastName': 'jackson',
...                  'middleName': 'marie'},
...         'maidenName': 'sanchez'}
```

It should work:

```
>>> print dict['maidenName']
sanchez
```

or If you are not sure that key exist or not

```
>>> dict.get('maidenName','default_return_data')
'sanchez'
```

Above will return **default_return_data** if maidenName key does **not** exist in dict.